# New window in tkinter with classes is blank

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I have some test code which defines a couple of windows and functions (one for show frame, one for new window). I have a bug creating the new_window function because instead of opening the specified window, it opens a blank one. I think it's because I've defined the windows in classes that relate to a master class, and frame is defined within that, but window is not, but I'm afraid I'm rather lost on how to debug.

Any help much appreciated!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

class Randomize(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Randomize those names!")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (HomeWindow, NewWin):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(HomeWindow)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

##trying to create a new window instead of just changing the original one        
    def new_window(self, cont):
        window = tk.Toplevel(self)
        window.tkraise() 

class HomeWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Choose a File and Start")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

##calls NewWin in a new frame but the same window, works     
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="File",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(NewWin))
        button.pack()
##should call NewWin through new_window, instead opens blank window    
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="New Window",
                            command=lambda: controller.new_window(NewWin))
        button2.pack()

class NewWin(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="NewWindow")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomeWindow))
        button1.pack()

app = Randomize()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `TopLevel` always creates empty window - code works correctly. Now you have to put `NewWin` frame inside this window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
def new_window(self, cont):
    window = tk.Toplevel(self)
    frame = cont(window, window) # cont = NewWin
    frame.pack()
```

but button in frame will not work. New window doesn't have `show_frame()` method.

Maybe if you use

```
    frame = cont(window, self) # self
```

then button in new window will change frame in main window.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful!